# Tooltip not showing up in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have used `title` attribute to show tool tip for `option` in `select` as shown in the code below:

```
<select>
    <option title="Hello 1">
        Hello 1
    </option>
    <option title="Hello 2">
        Hello 2
    </option>
<select>
```

But the tool tip works in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work in Safari 5.1.7 . Can any know how to fix this or any work around for this issue. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vkwBR/)

***NOTE:*** I can't use `mutiple="multiple"` attribute on `select`

Comment: i dint find any tooltip in demo

Comment: @Kamlesh Arya on option of drop down

Comment: Down voters care to comment?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select option').each(function () {
        $(this).attr({ 'title': $(this).html() });
    });
});
```

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/vkwBR/1/

Comment: The question is asking how to get the title attribute to render as a tooltip, not how to overwrite the title attribute with the text inside the option element.